# Most efficient way of changing speed mid interval?

Tags: javascript

I want to change the speed of steinterval() while running I tried something like this:

```
inteval = 1;
setInterval(function(){
    }, interval);
interval = 2;
```

Then I tried this which doesn't use intervals, but seems to work fine:

```
// Time
inteval = 1;
function refresh() {
    setTimeout(function() {refresh()},interval);
    }
refresh();
interval = 2;
```

I would rather have used setinterval() but this approach works fine. However in another similar question there is a longer approach: [Changing the interval of SetInterval while it's running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280263/changing-the-interval-of-setinterval-while-its-running)

If my snippet good in terms of efficiency? Is there a more efficient approach?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
var interval = 1000;
var times = 0;

function runInterval() {
    times ++;
    if(times == 5) {
        interval = 3000;
        clearInterval(s);
        s = setInterval(runInterval, interval);
    }
    console.log(times);
}
var s = setInterval(runInterval, interval);​
```

If you want to use setInterval, this is a way to do it. I hope it can help you