# Changing Setinterval at onclick

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to change the speed (setinterval) on this two boxes with onclick function.
So far i get the two boxes changing color and i setInterval by 1000(ms) , and now i want to click either one of the boxes and i want them to change the speed of color.

```js
 setInterval(
    function(){
        if (quadraDo == true) {
            document.getElementById("demo0").style.background = "red"
            document.getElementById("demo1").style.background = "blue";
            
            quadraDo = false;
        }
        else if (quadraDo == false) {
            document.getElementById("demo0").style.background = "blue";
            document.getElementById("demo1").style.background = "red";
            quadraDo = true;
        }
    
    
    }, 1000);
```

```html
    <div id="demo0" style="position: absolute;background-color: chartreuse ; width: 100px;height: 100px;left: 100px;top: 100px;"  onclick="myFunction(this)"></div>
    <div id="demo1" style="position: absolute;background-color: chartreuse ; width: 100px;height: 100px;left: 300px;top: 100px;"  onclick="myFunction(this)"></div>
```

Comment: You'd have to cancel the timer and start a new one. You can't change an already-started interval timer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing the interval of SetInterval while it's running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280263/changing-the-interval-of-setinterval-while-its-running)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the interval dynamically when using setInterval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35442258/how-to-change-the-interval-dynamically-when-using-setinterval)

Answer (score 1):

A bit of explanation. I've used your code to create a function `changeColor` which works with the initial interval speed of 1000ms

Then upon clicking any of the squares, the initial timer is cleared and a new one is started with a different interval speed. In this case:

- clicking on the first square slows down the initial tempo (x0.5) or 500ms
- clicking on the second one speeds up the initial tempo (x2) or 2000ms

That way `myFunction` is reused for setting the initial tempo and changing the tempo upon clicking. The essential part is to clear the current interval before starting a new one.

```js
let quadraDo = false;
function changeColor() {
  if (quadraDo == true) {
    document.getElementById("demo0").style.background = "red";
    document.getElementById("demo1").style.background = "blue";
    quadraDo = false;
  } else if (quadraDo == false) {
    document.getElementById("demo0").style.background = "blue";
    document.getElementById("demo1").style.background = "red";
    quadraDo = true;
  }
}

function myFunction(speed) {
  clearInterval(timer);
  timer = setInterval(changeColor, speed);
}

let timer = setInterval(changeColor, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="demo0" style="position: absolute;background-color: chartreuse ; width: 100px;height: 100px;left: 100px;top: 100px;"  onclick="myFunction(500)"></div>
<div id="demo1" style="position: absolute;background-color: chartreuse ; width: 100px;height: 100px;left: 300px;top: 100px;"  onclick="myFunction(2000)"></div>
```

By the way you have a typo while copy-pasting in your code:

```html
document.getElementById.setInterval("demo0",100).style.background = "red"
```

should be:

```html
document.getElementById("demo0").style.background = "red"
```