# Javascript increasing a value and the velocity on increasing it

Tags: javascript, html, time, settimeout, setinterval

I need to increase a number and I used `setInterval(Function, time)`
so I put a variable for time: `time = 1000` now I need to change it so I put a function that changes it when I click a button:

```
function changetime() {time = time - 100;}
```

but it seems that you can't change the time of `setInterval` while is working...
how can I do that?
I tried with a `setTimeout` but the number now changes "jumping". is not regular...
I'm not sure but it seems that the "jump" changes when I change the `setTimeout` time... like if the timeout is now in the `setInterval` time.

Original code---_>

```
var time = 1000;
function interval() { setInterval(Function, time);}
function changetime() {setTimeout(interval, 10);tempo = tempo - 200;}
```

Comment: thanks for the help....
now in the console i have that time changes.... from 1000 it changes in 800 but the number still jump....

Comment: here's answer for your question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280263/changing-the-interval-of-setinterval-while-its-running

Comment: i think this post is only for DEcelerating time... i need to speed it up. if you decrease the time for the loop of setInterval it goes faster...

Comment: ok i solved! it was a better idea to do that with the SetTimeout and then recall it because in settimeout is possible to change time...
Thank you anyway....
:D

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem some time ago, and i made a small function that can do this:
https://github.com/Atticweb/smart-interval/blob/master/smart-interval.js

It works like this:

```
var timer = new timer();
timer.start(function(){
    //more magic here
}, 3000, true);

//change the interval
timer.set_interval(4000);
```

I hope this helps you, good luck!