# setTimeout - counter increasing speed exponentially

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, setinterval

what i am trying to do is a function that prints out a sequence of numbers (eg. 1-100) in a given time (eg. 2 seconds). super easy.

The hardest part is that the sequence animation should begin slowly and **speed up exponentially**. This is what i have so far:

```
var animationLength = 2000; //ms

var counter = 0,
    counterEnd = 100,
    countInterval = animationLength / counterEnd; // 20ms

function animate() {
  $('#result').text(counter++);
  if (counter <= counterEnd) {

    //Calculate here dynamically newInterval
    var newInterval = countInterval;

    countInterval = newInterval;
    setTimeout(animate, newInterval);
  }
}

animate();
```

---

So, now `countInterval` is constantly *20ms*, but it should be variable, decreasing exponentially. Eg:

```
counter = 1; => countInterval = 40ms //not sure about that
...
counter = 100; => countInterval = 1ms
```

And the **summatory** of these intervals has to be **2000ms**

https://jsfiddle.net/fvxf7mby/5/

---

UPDATE:

thanks to @Mats Lind i finally found out. That's the final code ([JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/fvxf7mby/7/))

```
var animationLength = 2000; //ms

var counter = 0,
    counterEnd = 100,
    countInterval = animationLength / counterEnd, // 20 ms,
    a = 1.05; //speed factor

var summatory = 0;

function animate() {
  $('#result').text(counter++);
  if (counter <= counterEnd) {

    //that's the formula:
    var newInterval = (animationLength-summatory) / ( (a - Math.pow(a, -(counterEnd-1))) / (a-1))

    summatory += newInterval;
    countInterval = newInterval;
    setTimeout(animate, newInterval);
  } else {
    $('#summatory').text(summatory); //should be 2000
  }
}

animate();
```

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1280279/5768908

Comment: `requestAnimation` frame calls a callback function with a timestamp that can be used to determine the time difference between two intervals. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Comment: Just remember that `setTimeout` minimum is currently 4ms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the "hardest part", the math question about speeding up exponentially:

With time-interval inversely proportional to speed, we like the time-interval to decrease. Exponentially mean a decrease with the same factor between each interval.

Call the factor 1/a and set the first time-interval to b, then next time-interval will be be b/a, the third b/a^2 and the n:th b/a^(n-1).

Total time for N timesteps is b*(a-a^-(N-1))/(a-1) (summation formula for an exponential series), excel formula; `=(a-a^-(N-1))/(a-1)`

Now we know total time 2000ms and number of steps 100, and have two unknown, b and a, but only one equation. So we can set a and have b given via the equation above b=total_time/((a-a^-(N-1))/(a-1)). The more we want time to "accelerate" the higher we should set a. To conclude:

time interval length for interval n>0: b/a^(n-1)

total_time: choose, in this example total_time = 2000ms

N: choose, in this example N=100

a: choose, higher the faster you want speed to increase

b=total_time/((a-a^-(N-1))/(a-1)).

Try for instance a = 1.05 which gives b = 95.96788204ms and all timesteps:

95.96788204
91.39798289
87.04569799
82.90066476
78.95301405
75.19334672
71.61271116
68.20258206
64.95484005
61.86175243
58.9159547
56.11043304
53.43850766
50.89381682
48.47030173
46.16219213
43.9639925
41.87046905
39.87663719
37.97774971
36.16928543
34.44693851
32.8066081
31.24438867
29.75656064
28.33958156
26.99007768
25.70483588
24.48079608
23.31504388
22.2048037
21.14743209
20.14041152
19.1813443
18.26794696
17.39804472
16.5695664
15.78053943
15.02908517
14.31341445
13.63182328
12.98268884
12.36446556
11.77568149
11.21493475
10.68089024
10.17227642
9.687882303
9.226554574
8.787194832
8.368756983
7.970244746
7.590709282
7.229246935
6.884997081
6.557140077
6.244895312
5.947519344
5.664304138
5.394575369
5.137690828
4.893038884
4.660037032
4.438130507
4.226790959
4.025515199
3.833823999
3.651260951
3.477391382
3.311801316
3.154096492
3.003901421
2.860858496
2.724627139
2.594882989
2.471317133
2.353635365
2.24155749
2.134816657
2.033158721
1.936341639
1.844134894
1.756318947
1.672684712
1.593033059
1.517174342
1.444927944
1.376121852
1.31059224
1.248183085
1.188745796
1.132138853
1.078227479
1.026883313
0.977984108
0.931413436
0.887060415
0.844819443
0.804589946
0.766276139

Comment: whoa, this looks like what i'm looking for, but i can't make it works that formula: `b=total_time/(*(a-a^-(N-1))/(a-1))`. what's that `*` ?

Comment: i must be missing something. i tried formula `b = total_time/((a-a^-(N-1))/(a-1))` replacing the variables with values you said: `b = 2000/((1.05-1.05^-(100-1))/(1.05-1))` but the result is `-1.010101010101011`

Comment: I'm cutting and pasting into excel and getting 95.96788204: exponent first -(100-1)= -99, Power then: -1.05^-99 = -0.00798... so we have 1.05-1.05^-(100-1) = 1.042.. so 2000/((1.05-1.05^-(100-1))/(1.05-1))=2000/(1.042/0.5)=2000/20.84...=95.96... You don't go wrong there, do you? What do you mean with "the result", not "b", then what?

Comment: big N is fixed at 100 so b is fixed and ready as per above. Now time interval length number two: small n is 2, interval length is b/(a^(n-1))=b/a = 91.39...

Comment: thanks! it works, check out https://jsfiddle.net/fvxf7mby/6/ :) last thing i don't get is why at the end summatory value is `1985.3628196047` instead of `2000`? check out that link

Comment: Try starting at n=1 instead of 0!

Answer (score 0):

This would be much easier with `setTimeout`:

```js
var animationLength = 1000; // 1 second
var counter = 0;
var counterEnd = 100;

function animate() {
  // Do stuff
  $('#output').text(counter++);
  animationLength *= 0.5; // not exponential - but speed will half on each iteration
  if (counter <= counterEnd) { // Stopping condition
    setTimeout(animate, animationLength);
  }
}

animate(); // Starting the "loop"
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: formula `animationLength *= 0.5` means that when counter = 1 `animationLength` value will be 1000, 2: 500ms, 3: 250ms... and 11: 1ms. What i expected was **100**: 1ms

Comment: Fair enough, I will post an update on that. But if you want 100 to be 1ms, your starting number will have to be outrageously huge for an exponential speed up.

Comment: be aware the animation should finish in exactly 2 seconds (`animationLength`)

Comment: 2 seconds ? and you want to see the exponential speed up in 2 secs ?

Comment: @YoYo why not? anyway that's an arbitrary value, you can set it to 5 seconds if you're more comfortable with that

Comment: You are going to battle with to get that right with timeout and interval. As Seb commented on your question, there is a min speed on the two - If you want exponential speedup

Comment: @NicholasRobinson i am aware of that, but is not that important. Anyway, i expect a sequence of exactly **100** numbers from 40 to 1, like this: [40, 40, ... 40, 39, 39, 38, ... 2, 2, 1, 1, 1] where the sum of all those numbers is  **2000**

Comment: @NicholasRobinson anyway that initial 40 is just a guess, it should be calculated

Comment: @pumpkinzzz what is exponential about that?

Comment: @NicholasRobinson what's the term then?

Comment: I have no idea, I don't think there is a term for that. For this to be exponential each delay should be double the speed (half the time) of that of the last delay. [1,2,4,8,16,32...]

Answer (score 0):

Using the fiddle mentioned in [A.Wolf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7445863/5336818) 's comment. Just edited his jsfiddle as per your require ment

```js
var counter = 1000;

var num = 1;
var myFunction = function(){
    counter = counter -20;
    
   $("#result").html(num);
   num++;
    if(num <=100)
    {
    timeout = setTimeout(myFunction, counter);
    }
}

var timeout = setTimeout(myFunction, counter);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result">

</div>
```

Comment: line `counter = counter -20;` seems to very arbitrary. the animation should finish exactly in the given time: 1 second in your example (2 in mine)

Comment: Exactly at what time interval you want to finish  ?

Comment: @pumpkinzzz :  How about this demo https://jsfiddle.net/amarsingh/86d4xhoz/

Comment: Then You need to tell me what should be the start interval and the end interval. You are not clear

Comment: if you see in the OP i calculated an average speed of 20ms. So i guess it should be a sequence of exactly **100** numbers (`counterEnd`) from 40 to 1, like this: [40, 40, ... 40, 39, 39, 38, ... 2, 2, 1, 1, 1] where the sum of all these numbers is 2000 (`animationLength`)