# Jquery. Change setInterval time while running

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I'm new to Jquery and I want to change the 2000 while the code is running

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
//do something
}, 2000);
```

Something like this:

```
var wait = 200;
var interval = setInterval(function() {

if(wait == 200)
{
wait = 100;
}

}, wait);
```

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the interval of SetInterval while it's running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280263/changing-the-interval-of-setinterval-while-its-running)

Comment: Oriel.F's link should do it. If you're not prepared to wait for the next call to the anonymous function before changing the timeout, then you'll have to do something slightly clever with it, probably involving `clearTimeout`.

Comment: Can you stop the loop and start again or is that a problem? `clearInterval(interval)` then `setInterval(fn, newTime)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop the loop

```
clearInterval(interval);
```

And start over with the new time:

```
interval = setInterval(fn, newTime);
```