# setting the duration of javascripts setInterval within the function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code running a slideshow. I want to be able to set the duration of the interval from within the function rather than use a static value - depending on other factors I'll add in later. Is this possible? the below does not seem to work.

Thanks

```
$('#slideshow > div:gt(0)').hide();
setInterval(function() { 
   $('#slideshow > div:first')
      .fadeOut(0)
      .next()
      .fadeIn(0)
      .end()
      .appendTo('#slideshow');
   window.duration = 1000;
 },  duration);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the interval of SetInterval while it's running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280263/changing-the-interval-of-setinterval-while-its-running)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout`.

Then you would have to call this function every time in your callback.

Something like

```
function myCallback() { 
    ...
    ...

    var myTime = 2435; // whatever depending on sth

    setTimeout(myCallback, myTime);
}

setTimeout(myCallback,  someInitialTime);
```

Comment: Thanks. But I don't see the difference? my question could equally be applied to setting the duration within the a function in setTimeout?

Comment: @BigJ If you use `createInterval` then you have created the interval with a specific duration.  Changing the variable that holds the duration at a later point *will not* change the duration that you originally used when you created the `setInterval`.  If you use `setTimeout` then it only runs once, which is why you call it again after your callback function has executed.  It has the same effect as `setInterval` in that respect, but it means you can modify the duration after every single timeout, if you want to.

Comment: @BigJ If my answer helped you, please mark it as correct.