# Variable inside setInterval(function, var) is not changing / updating with increment

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I am building a browser pet raising game. My plan is to use if/else to determine what the HP drop rate should be for the pet. If below a certain hunger / happiness, the HP will drop faster and faster.

I am using a variable setInterval, and the value inside is not update, but the value is updating when printing to the console.

```
let hp = 100;
let dropHPWeight = 6000;
let dropHPCall = setInterval(dropHP, dropHPWeight);

  function dropHP() {
    hp = (hp % 360) - 1;
    console.log(dropHPWeight);
    dropHPWeight = dropHPWeight + 6000;
  }
```

Here I am dropping the HP every 6 seconds, and then as a test, I am seeing if it will increase, but it does not.

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: What's "hp" here? And how will this go faster and faster if you keep adding time? And it's always the first interval's time if you only call "setInterval" once.

Comment: `setInterval(dropHP, dropHPWeight)` does not store the actual variable, the `dropHPWaight` variable is being evaluated and it's value (6000) is being passed to `setInterval`. Raising the variable's value will not change the interval.

Comment: is there a way to update the variable? @MrLumie

Comment: @DaveNewton My apologies. ill update post. HP = 100;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing the interval of SetInterval while it's running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280263/changing-the-interval-of-setinterval-while-its-running)

Comment: It's more likely Heritic's reference is what you're looking for, e.g., at the end of the timeout, call `setTimeout` again w/ the same method argument and the new time. Once a `setInterval` is started, it will always have the same interval (that's the point of it).

Answer (score 0):

As some are mentioning in the comments, you cannot change the interval of a `setInterval` once it has been initiated.  You are better off [using `setTimeout`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280263/changing-the-interval-of-setinterval-while-its-running).  Like this:

```js
let hp = 100;
let dropHPWait = 6000;

function dropHP() {

  hp = (hp % 360) - 1;
  dropHPWeight = dropHPWait + 6000;

  if (somecondition){
    setTimeout(dropHP, dropHPWait)
  }

}

dropHP()
```

Now you call `dropHP`, which changes the interval, and then uses `setTimeout` to call itself again after the given increment.  I stuck the `setTimeout` inside some conditional, because you don't want it to run forever (so you have to decide at what point you want it to stop running).