# Change interval of setTimeout such that a countdown from 100 slows down and should take exactly 10 seconds (in Svelte)

Tags: javascript, math, settimeout, svelte

Based on this SO answer:
[Changing the interval of SetInterval while it's running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280263/changing-the-interval-of-setinterval-while-its-running)

I created this mini Svelte-Repl:
https://svelte.dev/repl/ae3987eff26446b49af4a85d029acd80?version=3.49.0

Which looks like this:

```js
<script>
let display = 100
let interval = 1;
let myFunction = function() {
    display--
    interval *= 1.07;
    setTimeout(myFunction, interval);
}
setTimeout(myFunction, interval);
</script>

{#if display > 0}
  {display}
{:else}
  End
{/if}
```

So the function `myFunction` calls itself while changing (increasing) the interval so that the count-down slows down. Now I would like to count down from 100 and slowly make the interval longer. I was thinking about the Math on how to achieve that, but couldn't work it out. I'd be grateful for any tips:)

### Update:

I guess the question is kind of badly expressed. The idea was to:

- Have a decreasing counter (`display`) from 100 to 0
- The speed in which this counter decreases should become smaller, meaning that changing from e.g. 90 to 89 takes less time than from 10 to 9
- The function in which it decreases does not matter. It can be exponentially, linearly or any other function. My aim was more about knowing how to solve this "generally"
- The entire process, decreasing the variable `display` from 100 to 0, should take (can also be roughly) 10 seconds.
- How would I do the Math?

Comment: I am always surprised to read this kind of method to develop a setInterval with variation of durations, whereas the methods setInterval and setTimeout have never offered a guarantee on their durations of their delays, it is also documented in the documentation .

Comment: Naming a delay variable 'counter' while trying to produce a countDown is something irrational and confusing

Comment: true, i'll change that

Comment: Do you really want the delay to increase exponentially?

Comment: And you are also right about their durations...:/ Is there any other way to achieve a de-accelerating counter that takes exactly 10 seconds?

Comment: @trincot I do not mind if it's exponentially or linearly or of any other form:)

Comment: There are countless ways to have a de-accelerating counter, each with their own characteristics. Just like there are many curves that go down...

Comment: yes you are right, I just did not know where to start or how to solve this with any kind of function, regardless of its type

Comment: yes, there is other ways, you need tu use timestanp testing (or maybe with css?). and please make a better delay progress computation   than an exponetial equation

Comment: You function should be something like `StartSpeed * Acceleration^X` I think. You should be able calculate the Acceleration with that

Comment: your question is poorly worded.
what does it mean to slow down the periods between your display's ?
--from what initial period?
--Is 10 seconds the total duration of seconds from 100 to zero?
--Is 10 seconds the duration of the last period between 1 and zero?

Comment: @MisterJojo You are right! I'll update the question

Comment: your min problem is about adding a period n(100), like `1 + 2 + 3 + 4...` until `100` see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of changing the interval times, have a fast rate (frame rate, with `requestAnimationRate`), and calculate the counter's value based on the timestamp (i.e. the time that has elapsed since the start of the count down).

I would go for a formula that does not lead to exponentially increasing delays, but a less "drastic" one. For instance, you could use this formula to translate elapsed time to a counter value:

```
initialCount - r * sqrt(elapsed_time)
```

The coefficient `r` is then determined by the requirement that after 10 seconds this expression should be zero, so that brings us to:

```
r = initialCount / sqrt(total_duration)
```

Instead of a square root (i.e. exponent 0.5), you could use another exponent. The derivation of the value of `r` remains the same then (using that exponent).

Here is an implementation, where I have also displayed the elapsed time, so to verify it works as intended:

```js
let [span, control] = document.querySelectorAll("span");

function countDown(counterStart, duration) {
    const exp = 0.3; // Between 0 and 1: determines the gravity of the slow-down
    let r = counterStart / duration ** exp;
    let startTime;
    
    function loop(timestamp) {
        if (!startTime) startTime = timestamp;
        const elapsed = timestamp - startTime;
        const counter = Math.ceil(counterStart - r * elapsed ** exp);
        span.textContent = Math.max(0, counter);
        control.textContent = Math.floor(elapsed / 100) / 10;
        if (counter > 0) requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

countDown(100, 10000);
```

```html
Count down: <span></span><br>
Elapsed time: <span></span>
```

If you wish to stick with exponentially increasing delays, then use a logarithm instead of a root:

```
initialCount - r * log(elapsed_time)
```

The code is very similar:

```js
let [span, control] = document.querySelectorAll("span");

function countDown(counterStart, duration) {
    let r = counterStart / Math.log(duration);
    let startTime;
    
    function loop(timestamp) {
        if (!startTime) startTime = timestamp;
        const elapsed = timestamp - startTime;
        const counter = Math.ceil(counterStart - r * Math.log(elapsed));
        span.textContent = Math.max(0, counter);
        control.textContent = Math.floor(elapsed / 100) / 10;
        if (counter > 0) requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

countDown(100, 10000);
```

```html
Count down: <span></span><br>
Elapsed time: <span></span>
```